# Retrieve data from relative table while sorting it by date field

Tags: greendao

I have a `schedule` entity which is in 1:n relation with a `broadcast` entity.

When I do somewhat like `mBroadcasts = schedules.get(0).getBroadcastList();` it sorts data by id. I need to sort data by date field of the `broadcast` entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a QueryBulder for create a select. For example, if you want to order by property date:

```
daoSession.getBroadcastDao().queryBuilder().orderAsc(Properties.Date);
```

If you need to create a complex condition WHERE...

```
QueryBuilder<Broadcast> qb = daoSession.getBroadcastDao().queryBuilder();
```

and then, add *and*, *or*, *equal*, *lt*, *gt*, ... or whatever you need.